# How to make Swift detect an NSError subclass used by Objective-C methods?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nserror

I am tidying up a large legacy Objective-C library for use inside a new Swift project.

Now normally an Objective-C method like `-initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:(NSError*)err` gets turned into `init(contentsOfFile path: String, encoding enc: UInt) throws` on the Swift side.

But in this legacy codebase we have a custom error subclass `@interface MyError : NSError`. This seems to break this automatic error conversion, so that a method like `-initWIthConfig:error:(MyError**)err` gets treated by Swift only as
`init(config: [String:Any], error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<MyError?>)` — which is not useful!

Now I see there is an `ErrorType` protocol on the Swift side but that does not seem relevant here. My own error type (`MyError`) already inherits from `NSError` and needs to stay that way on the Objective-C side.

How do I get Swift to recognize my custom error subclass as an error type, so that it treats each method that uses it into one which `throws`? I am able to edit the legacy framework, but am not sure how I can annotate these methods for conversion.

Comment: (Cross-posted this basic questino to https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/291928 btw.)